# Add event listener to dynamically create table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a table with ajax call to create rows within the tbody element. I have the table created on the html page.

```
<table id='mytable'>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>First Col</th>
<th>Second Col</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>
```

My  javascript code to attach the event to second cell of each row in tbody

```
$('#mytable tbody').on( 'click', 'tr td:eq(2)',  function() {
    console.log($(this).html())
});
```

This code only works for the second cell of the first row of the tbody. Clicking the second cell of all other rows did not trigger the event. I have  to work around this by check the cell index

```
if (this.cellIndex == 2) console.log($(this).html())
```

I still want to know how to make the correct selection.

Comment: What element has the ID #lessons?

Comment: @j08691 I fixed the typo, the it should be the table id on the jquery statement

Comment: Use `nth-child(3)` instead of `eq(2)` if you want it to work for all rows.

Comment: Glad it helped. I added it as an answer for you

Comment: @user1941319 could the td elements have an attribute either an ID or a class name? Then you can select for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select the specific `td` of each row use `nth-child()` instead of `eq()`:

```
$('#mytable tbody').on( 'click', 'tr td:nth-child(3)',  function() {
  console.log($(this).html())
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just have an event listener for the entire table and then test what was clicked. Adding the event listener to the table you don't need to assign it again if the content of the table changes.

Adding a class name can both be useful for the usability (styling the cursor) and easier to find elements using JS.

```js
document.getElementById('mytable').addEventListener('click', e => {
  let td = e.target.closest('td[class="clickable"]');
  if (td) {
    console.log(e.target.innerText, 'was clicked');
  }
});
```

```css
td.clickable {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<table id='mytable'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First Col</th>
      <th>Second Col</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>First</td>
      <td class="clickable">Second 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>First</td>
      <td class="clickable">Second 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>First</td>
      <td class="clickable">Second 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>First</td>
      <td class="clickable">Second 4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```